# Polymer 2.0 calling functions

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have question about publishing/ building element in Polymer 2.0

I make polymer 2 application using bower. Then I coded my element. I can use it in this project when i call `<my-element></my-element>` in index.html.

In my Polymer class i have some functions. What should I do in my new project where I will import my  builded element `<my-element></my-element>` to call this functions? 
For example I will have some file form.html, and in this i will have `<my-element></my-element>`. What I should do in `<script></script>` to call for example `my-element.myFunction();`?

Answer (score 1):

absolutely the same as you do in all other elements. Are you using some paper-elements in your project? are you calling some functions on them?

Let's say you have element

```
<my-element id="myElement"></my-element>
```

and then in `<script>` tag

```
this.$.myElement.someFunction();
```

imagine your element as some Wrapper for all functions and properties. Defining `<my-element>` in your code creates instance of it and then through DOM you need to get to it. Normaly in HTML you do `document.getElementById("someID")` but here, in polymer (if you are using shadow-dom) you just need to do `this.getElementById("someID")` or in shorthand `this.$.someID`. So first step is get that element and second is to call function or property. `this.$.someID.someFunction()`

First, you need to understand some basics of polymer. Try the starting tutorial on polymer. And don't forget that all elements you create, behave absolutely same way as polymer's elements. Your element will have just different styling, functions and properties

Comment: okay, i will try to do this by this way, and then I will marked as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you open your inspector and select your custom element and go to the inspector's console type $0. You will get a dropdown containing that method also.